# How do i change what the the values contain within the variables such as using a percentage?

Tags: python, tkinter

The below code is supposed to be a stock management system for a business so the user is able to change the price of goods that have stayed too long within the business (unable to sell)

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
import random
import datetime
import time;
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
start = Tk()
start.geometry("100x600+0+0")
start.title ("R.E.D Inventory Control System")


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Heading = Frame(start, width = 1000, height = 100, bd = 10, relief = 'raise')
Heading.pack(side = TOP)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
LowerHeading = Frame(start, width = 500, height  = 100, bd = 20, relief = 'raise')
LowerHeading.pack(side = BOTTOM)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
LMiddle = Frame(start, width = 500, height = 1000, bd = 12, relief = 'raise')
LMiddle.pack(side = LEFT)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
RMiddle = Frame(start, width = 500, height = 1000, bd = 12, relief = 'raise')
RMiddle.pack(side=RIGHT)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Title = Label(Heading, font=('arial',40,'bold'), text = "R.E.D Inventory Control System", bd = 10, width = 40, anchor = 'w')
          #justify = 'center')
Title.grid(row=0,column=0)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
info1=StringVar()
info2=StringVar()
info3=StringVar()
info4=StringVar()
info5=StringVar()
info6=StringVar()
info7=StringVar()
info8=StringVar()


info1.set("")
info2.set("")
info3.set("")
info4.set("")
info5.set("")
info6.set("")
info7.set("")
info8.set("")
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def Product(event):
    if (info1.get()=="ID01"):
        info2.set("Dress")
        info3.set("03/08/2016")
        info4.set("£8")
        info5.set("74")
        info6.set("Spring")
        if (info7.get()=="10%"):
                Calculation=info4/0.1
                info8.set(Calculation)
```

1) The above code doesn't work as when the user clicks "10%" on the GUI the new price variable is supposed to change accordingly. Not only for 10% but for the other values too.

```
    elif (info1.get()=="ID02"):
        info2.set("Shoes")
        info3.set("25/03/2017")
        info4.set("£4")
        info5.set("24")
        info6.set("Spring")
        if (info7.get()=="10%"):
                Calculation=info4/0.1
                info8.set(Calculation)
    elif (info1.get()=="ID03"):
        info2.set("Belt")
        info3.set("16/08/2017")
        info4.set("£1.50")
        info5.set("36")
        info6.set("Spring")
        if (info7.get()=="10%"):
                Calculation=info4/0.1
                info8.set(Calculation)
    elif (info1.get()=="ID04"):
        info2.set("Blazer")
        info3.set("18/05/2016")
        info4.set("£18")
        info5.set("96")
        info6.set("Spring")
        if (info7.get()=="10%"):
                Calculation=info4/0.1
                info8.set(Calculation)
    elif (info1.get()=="ID05"):
        info2.set("Skirt")
        info3.set("27/06/2017")
        info4.set("£5")
        info5.set("47")
        info6.set("Spring")
        if (info7.get()=="10%"):
                Calculation=info4/0.1
                info8.set(Calculation)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
ProductID = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'),text = "Product ID", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
ProductID.grid(row=0,column=0)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
ProductsID = ttk.Combobox(LMiddle, textvariable = info1 ,state='readonly', font=('arial',12,'bold'),  width =20)
ProductsID['value']=('','ID01','ID02','ID03','ID04','ID05')
ProductsID.current(0)
ProductsID.grid(row=0,column=1)
ProductsID.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", Product)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Description1 = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'),text ="Description", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
Description1.grid(row=2,column=0)
Description2 = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), textvariable = info2, bd = 10, width = 18, relief = 'sunken')
Description2.grid(row=2,column=1)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
DateStockBought1 = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Date Stock Bought", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
DateStockBought1.grid(row=3,column=0)
DateStockBought2 = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), textvariable = info3, bd = 10, width = 18, relief = 'sunken')
DateStockBought2.grid(row=3,column=1)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Price1 = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Price", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
Price1.grid(row=4,column=0)
Price2 = Label(LMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), textvariable = info4, bd = 10, width = 18, relief = 'sunken')
Price2.grid(row=4,column=1)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
AmountLeft1 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Amount Left", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
AmountLeft1.grid(row=1,column=0)
AmountLeft2 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), textvariable = info5,bd = 10, width = 18, relief = 'sunken')
AmountLeft2.grid(row=1,column=1)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
CurrentSeason1 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="CurrentSeason", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
CurrentSeason1.grid(row=2,column=0)
CurrentSeason2 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), textvariable = info6, bd = 10, width = 18, relief = 'sunken')
CurrentSeason2.grid(row=2,column=1)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Discount1 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'),text = "Discount", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
Discount1.grid(row=3,column=0)

Discount1 = ttk.Combobox(RMiddle , textvariable=info7, state='readonly', font=('arial',12,'bold'),  width =20)
Discount1['value']=('','10%','20%','30%','40%','50%')
Discount1.current(0)
Discount1.grid(row=3,column=1)
Discount1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", Product)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
NewPrice1 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="New Price", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
NewPrice1.grid(row=4,column=0)
NewPrice2 = Label(RMiddle, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable = info8, bd = 10, width = 18, relief = 'sunken')
NewPrice2.grid(row=4,column=1)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
LH=Label(LowerHeading, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Update", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
LH.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

2) How do i put all the information within a csv file? So the user can change the price of the products?

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
start.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"code doesn't work" is not a problem specification.  You've provided far too much code for a single problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sholudn't Calculation be a string? When you do:

```
Calculation=info4/0.1
```

you're dividing a StringVariable by 0.1. You should convert to a number, do the math, and then convert to String again

Actually, I'd suggest not using "£" or "$" or "%" on numeric fields and not using StringValue() for values that are clearly not intended to store Strings (if you want to do math to it, then it's not a String)

As for the csv file, check the Python's own [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Quick example here

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\****\*****\Inventory (new).py", line 57, in Product
    Calculation=info4/0.1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IntVar' and 'float'
>>>

Comment: I got the above Error when changing the info4 variable to info4 variable to intvar

Comment: could you help me please?